# Telescoping Series Question

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac1{16k^2+8k-3}$$

I did this and got $-1$, the book says $-1/4$, and for some reason they are pulling out a $1/4$ early on in the steps and i do not understand why the $1/4$ is pulled out.  I did partial decomposion and got

$$\frac1{4k-1}-\frac1{4k+3}$$

however, in the book its written as

$$\frac14\left(\frac1{4k-1}-\frac1{4k+3}\right)\;?$$

Could someone please tell me why the $1/4$ is taken out?  Thanks.

Comment: Your partial fractions decomposition is not quite right; theirs is. To see the error (and why theirs is right), put $1/(4k-1) - 1/(4k-3)$ under a common denominator, and see what the numerator is. You have made a small error in solving the linear system obtained by performing partial fractions decomposition.

Comment: Okay I see, how can I avoid this and do it the right way? Is there a trick I should know when it comes to problems like these?

Comment: I think the way you did it is likely just fine. I'm wary of making any generalizations, so I guess my recommendation is to just be careful with your computations, and you should be good to go.

Comment: Yeah i'm looking at it and I still can't figure out how the 1/4 came out, could someone guide me through the first few steps on how that comes to be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $${1\over 16k^2+8k-3}={1\over (4k-1)(4k+3)}.$$ Let $${1\over (4k-1)(4k+3)}={A\over 4k-1}+{B\over 4k+3}.$$ Multiplying both sides of the above equation by $(4k-1)(4k+3)$ gives us $$1=A(4k+3)+B(4k-1).$$ So $$1=(4A+4B)k+3A-B.$$ Thus $0=4A+4B$ and $1=3A-B$. We obtain $A={1\over 4}$ and $B={-1\over 4}$. This gives us $${1\over 4}({1\over 4k-1}-{1\over 4k+3}).$$